# Change the data type of a table in SQL Server via Visual Studio (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, currency, nvarchar

Change the data type of a table in SQL Server via Visual Studio (C#)

**Context**

- I have a web scraper that I use to pull data from various websites each morning (via automated tasks).
- Each scraper project then creates a separate SQL Server table and populates it with the extracted data.

**Problem**

- My problem is that the web scraper will only use `nvarchar(4000)` as the data type for every column.
- I need to consume the data from the auto-generated tables in C# code.
- The column in question (again remembering that this table is auto-generated by the web scraper) is consistent and holds data that looks like "$12.34".
- When I consume the data I need "$12.34" to be a decimal (or some other numeric format) so that I can do comparisons to other numeric values.

**Tried**

- My first thought was to simply do a `Convert.ToDecimal(myDecimalStringNum)`, but that throws a `System.FormatException`.
- I also tried `Decimal.Parse` in case it was a culture issue; same result.
- I tried programatically (from VB or C#) changing the column data type from `nvarchar` to `decimal`, didn't work.  Incidentally, I couldn't even change the data type from `nvarchar` to `decimal` in SSMS.
- One thing that DOES work is changing the data type for the column from `nvarchar(4000)` to money using SSMS. From the money data type I can successfully use `Convert.ToDecimal`.

**Question**

The problem, C# doesn't have a "money" data type that I can use to change the column in SQL Server to `money`. All the web scraping, SQL Server table generation, and the C# program that uses the tables need to run automatically each morning.

I'm 99% of the way there, I just need a solution to this problem that can be added to my automated workflow. As of now that looks like figuring out a way to automate changing the auto-generated table's column data type from `nvarchar(4000)` to money in SSMS, but I'm open to other suggestions!

Comment: In C# you can use `decimal.Parse("$12.34", NumberStyles.Currency, new CultureInfo("en-us"));`. You should specify NumberStyle and FormatProvider.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the SQL to read from the table then you could use convert on the SQL query:

```
select CONVERT(money, '$123.34')
```

replacing '$123.34' with your column.  Then C# should be able to use that as a Decimal.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post and you have figured this out by now, but if you need to do the conversion in C# I would first do a:

```
myDecimalStringNum = myDecimalStringNum.Replace("$","");
```

and then do the conversion as you were at first:

```
var newDecimalStringNum = Convert.ToDecimal(myDecimalStringNum);
```